# How do I get a G Suite user's tenant Id

Tags: google-apps-script, google-oauth, google-workspace

I am creating an application which can only be used by G Suite users. I want the billing to happen at a tenant(team/org) level, i.e every user in the G Suite tenant will be part of the application tenant. My challenge is - How do I get a user's org details? I am asking for "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile" permission but that only returns a "hd" (host domain) value(along with name, email, language and timezone). I cannot map a user against the host domain since a G suite tenant can have multiple domains. I tried searching within the Google API engine but am unable to find the right endpoint for this.

Comment: Have you tried Google support?

Comment: @geocodezip Google Support redirects to StackOverflow :) I was super surprised there's no dedicated Google Support page

Comment: Not for non-coding questions.  From [support (third item on the list)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/support): [Contact the Maps support team](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/support#contact_maps_support)

Comment: @geocodezip this is a coding question and has nothing to do with google maps

Comment: So what you are looking for is the GSuite team a user is a member of?  Unfortunately i dont think the information you are looking for is available.

Comment: If this has nothing to do with google maps, please remove the [google-maps] tag.

Comment: @zenCoder Were you ever able to get a solution for this?